# Export location

Tags: scripting

I did a small simulation using ridig bodies. I would like to write (possibly to a file) the location of each object for a specified frame. Objects are spheres with different radii.

Is it possible?

I found a small script to print the location on the command line, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
sphere=bpy.data.objects['Sphere01']
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(50)
print(sphere.location)
```

It always returns the location corresponding to the initial frame (start).

Any help?

Comment: Can you try two subsequent calls to `frame_set()` and `print(sphere.matrix_world.translation)`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the animation data first. Like using the bake action function:
object->animation->bake actions...

Comment: The animation data must already be stored somewhere (i.e. the rigid body cache), otherwise blender wouldn't know where the objects are at all..